# How to detect changes on @Input string

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have the following code in my child component:

1. Component

```
@Input() query: string;

ngOnChanges(changes) {
   if (changes['query']) {
     console.log('query is now: ', this.query);
   }
}
```

2. Template

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="query">
```

Then in my parent component I have the following:
1. Template

```
<my-input 
   (onSearch)="searchSelected($event)"             
   [searchTerm]="selectedSearch">
</my-input>

<span>search is: {{selectedSearch}}</span>
```

My problem is whenever I type in my-input component it never updates selectedSearch in the parent. Also, when I set selectedSearch in the parent component it does not get updated on the child (ngOnChanges does not trigger also). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need either code of two components that you have problem with or StackBlitz

Answer (score 1):

You child component is expecting a `query` input. You are giving it a `seachTerm` props when using it.

You need to change the input name to

```
@Input() searchTerm: string;
```

or modify how you are using the component to use the correct input

```
<my-input [query]="selectedSearch"></my-input>
```

Onto the output now. You actually need to create an output on your child component

```
@Output() onSearch = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

And then call the `EventEmitter` when you want the `onSearch` prop to trigger

```
this.onSearch.emit(my_value)
```

You can find more documentation on the subject here:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can use get/set

```
  private _query

  @Input()
  get query(): string {
    return this._query;
  }

  set query(value: string) {
    this._query= value;
    // do some logic on set
  }
```

Comment: This isn't the issue here, its both components not communicating properly through inputs/outputs